# Shell Script could not execute all if else statements in script

Tags: shell

I have the following script to be executed in bash

```
#!/bin/bash
###
### Author: Sam
###
Usage(){
    echo "Script Location: /fsnadmin/Warroom_sustenance/p4fa_automate"
    echo "Usage: P4FA_automate.sh  LBOX_PSWD"
}

if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
Usage
    exit 0
fi

LBOX_PSWD="$1"
LBOX_PSWD=`echo $LBOX_PSWD`

# source the properties:
. /fsnadmin/Warroom_sustenance/p4fa_automate/input.properties

echo "NumberOfPods = $NumberOfPods"
echo "MC_HOST = $MC_HOST"
echo "MC_ROOT_USER = $MC_ROOT_USER"
echo "MC_ROOT_PSWD = $MC_ROOT_PSWD"
echo "LBOX_USER = $LBOX_USER"
echo "LBOX_HOST = $LBOX_HOST"
echo "RELEASE = $RELEASE"
echo "E2EPATH = $E2EPATH"
echo "P4FALABEL = $P4FALABEL"
echo "P4FA_LOCATION = $P4FA_LOCATION"
echo "EXTONEOFFS_LABEL = $EXTONEOFFS_LABEL"
echo "EXTONEOFFS_LOCATION = $EXTONEOFFS_LOCATION"
echo "BIPB_LABEL = $BIPB_LABEL"
echo "BIPB_LOCATION = $BIPB_LOCATION"
echo "BIPB_HOST = $BIPB_HOST"
echo "FAPB_LABEL = $FAPB_LABEL"
echo "FAPB_LOCATION = $FAPB_LOCATION"
echo "FAPB_HOST = $FAPB_HOST"

if [ ! -d ${E2EPATH}/patches/${RELEASE}/P4FA/${P4FALABEL} ]; then
        mkdir -p ${E2EPATH}/patches/${RELEASE}/P4FA/${P4FALABEL}
        echo "Created path ${E2EPATH}/patches/${RELEASE}/P4FA/${P4FALABEL}"
else
        echo "Path ${E2EPATH}/patches/${RELEASE}/P4FA/${P4FALABEL} already exists"
fi
```

The script does not execute all statements in if-else and gives the following output:

```
NumberOfPods = 2
MC_HOST = host.com
MC_ROOT_USER = toor
MC_ROOT_PSWD = toor
LBOX_USER = user1
LBOX_HOST = host.com
RELEASE = 11
E2EPATH = /admin/sustenance/E2E_M4_PC6
P4FALABEL = PATCHES4FA_11.1.11.1.0ONEOFFS.1.S
P4FA_LOCATION = /autofs/gd14/160308.0946.1.S/patches4fa/dist
EXTONEOFFS_LABEL = PATCHES4FAEXTONEOFFS_PLATFORMS_160321.1032.S
EXTONEOFFS_LOCATION = /autofs/gd14/PATCHES4/patches4fa/dist/rel111extoneoffs
BIPB_LABEL = bi_rel11
BIPB_LOCATION = /scratch/saaspb/rel11.tar.gz
BIPB_HOST = host.com
FAPB_LABEL = gsi_rel11
FAPB_LOCATION = /scratch//erp/gsi_rel11.tar.gz
FAPB_HOST = host.com
 already existsA_11.1.11.1.0ONEOFFS.1.S
```

It does not check if directory exist nor executes mkdir command.
The directory does not exist, but it displays already exists, with half the label name
It seems as if it executes last echo statement in script and that too partially

Need help to resolve it

Comment: Run `dos2unix` on the script.  You've got bad line endings.

Comment: Also run dos2unix on the file you source.